# scandir() with php to create ordered list from array

Tags: php, scandir

Reading up on `scandir()`, having an issue getting anything to display.

```
<?php
    $dir = 'http://www.universaldynamicmedia.com/sandbox/Images';
    $array = scandir($dir);
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            echo '<li><img src="' . $dir . $value . '" /></li>';
        }
?>
```

I supposed I'm not doing something right with the directory and `scandir()` as the other stuff, I've done before and it works fine.

Would directory permissions cause an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** Note you cannot use a URL, you must have access to the folders/files

scandir():

```
$dir = "PATH_TO_DIRECTORY";
$exclude = array( ".","..","error_log","_notes" );
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(!in_array($file,$exclude)){
            echo '<li><img src="' . $dir . $file . '" /></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

readdir():

```
$dir = "PATH_TO_DIRECTORY";
$exclude = array( ".","..","error_log","_notes" );
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(!in_array($file,$exclude))
                 echo '<li><img src="' . $dir . $file . '" /></li>';
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Not with `scandir()` he doesn't. You're talking about `readdir()`.

Answer (score 2):

`scandir()` only works on local filesystems, you need to change that to:

```
$dir = '/path/to/document/root/sandbox/Images';
```

Comment: Well that is an iis so I expect that is a windows server.

Comment: So that's the actual file system path? `C:/my/directory/root/sandbox/images`?

Comment: @Plummer: Yup, that should be it. Be sure to append the trailing slash.

Comment: @Axil: Sweet.  Thanks.  I assume the directory is going to need IIS user permissions as well?

Comment: @Plummer: I know nothing about IIS, but it should need some kind of reading permissions, yes.

Comment: @rekire: Ah, I see. Nice catch. =P